# undefined reference to `main' using Autotools

Tags: c, linker-errors, autotools

I have a little program, when I run `make` this error appears:

```
$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: se ingresa al directorio «/home/foo/boolham»
Making all in src
make[2]: se ingresa al directorio «/home/foo/boolham/src»
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2   -o set set.o  
libtool: link: gcc -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -o set set.o 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [set] Error 1
make[2]: se sale del directorio «/home/foo/boolham/src»
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: se sale del directorio «/home/foo/boolham»
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My `Makefile.am` has:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfsequence.la
libfsequence_la_SOURCES = fsequence.c fsequence.h

bin_PROGRAMS = set main

main_SOURCES = main.c main.h
set_SOURCES = set.c set.h

main_LDADD = libfsequence.la
```

`main.c` has only `int main()` function, `set.c` has sets functions and `fsequences.c` has functions to generate sequences of numbers. `fsequences.c` includes `set.h` as a utility functions and `main.c` includes `fsequences.h`.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little shot in the dark, but I guess your set.c file is a file without main. Then You should not treat it as a program - it should be compiled with -c option (so .o file will be generated and linked with main).

I'm not familiar with autotools, but you should check some examples how to do that.

**EDIT:**

according to: http://socgsa.cs.clemson.edu/seminar/tools06/resources/08_autotools/automake.htm you just should remove 'set' from 'bin_PROGRAMS'

Comment: yes you are right, `set.c` does not have `main` function, but I do not know how to set `-c` flag into `Makefile.am` (or any place which I should do this, do not forget I am using autotools). :(

Comment: Thank you, I have solved this changing a few lines: first changed to: `bin_PROGRAMS = main` and second one to: `main_SOURCES = main.c main.h set.c set.h`.

Comment: @Israel: :) anyway If you start learning autotools and you want to use them for your projects, consider cmake usage. It's simplier I believe, and more common nowadays